# AnnotationException when @MapKey refers to a column mapped in embeddable map value

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

**Use case**

I've got a User entity which contains a map of UserProfiles, as you can see UserProfile is mapped as an Element collection, not as an individual entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_")
public class User extends AbstractEntity<UserId> {

    ...

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_profile")
    @MapKey(name = "userProfileType")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(STRING)
    private Map<UserProfileType, UserProfile> userProfiles;

}

@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PACKAGE)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserProfile {

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private UserProfileType userProfileType;

    ...

}
```

Note: I'm using Hibernate 5.2.14.

**Issue**

When Hibernate processes these mappings, I can the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not found: UserProfile
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder.bindKeyFromAssociationTable(MapBinder.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder.access$000(MapBinder.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder$1.secondPass(MapBinder.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1635) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1603) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

**Workarounds tried**

I tried to use `@MapKeyColumn` instead of `@MapKey`, but that generates another error claiming that a physical representation of column `user_profile_type` already exists.

**Question**

I wondering if this is supposed to work according to the JPA spec?

I think it should work, because I found a very similar issue which had already been fixed in Hibernate 5: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5393

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
László

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Annoying.

Comment: Appears not to be fixed in Hibernate: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5393

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't worked on this project lately, I can see that I checked the code in the following way into Git a few days after posting the question to SoF.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_")
public class User extends AbstractEntity<UserId> {

  ...

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "user_profile")
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "user_profile_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @MapKeyEnumerated(STRING)
  private Map<UserProfileType, UserProfile> userProfiles;

  ...

}

@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PACKAGE)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(of = {"userProfileType", "fullName"})
public class UserProfile {

  @Enumerated(STRING)
  @Column(name = "user_profile_type")
  private UserProfileType userProfileType;

  ...

}

public enum UserProfileType {
  FACEBOOK, GOOGLE;
}
```

Trick, I think, must have been adding `insertable = false, updatable = false` and that eliminates that error that `user_profile_type` has already been defined.